# Display ACF User Field on Frontend

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am trying to display an ACF user field on the front end, but I only want to have the display name and the users email show up. Here is what I have so far, but on the frontend a random string shows up. I debugged the $user variable with print_r() and the array shows all the info correctly. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
// retrieve "pds_project_manager" field from the post id ""
$pds_project_manager = get_field('pds_project_manager', "");
// loop over users
foreach($pds_project_manager as $user){
$user_id = $user['ID'];
$user_email = $user['user_email'];
$user_display_name = $user['display_name'];
echo "$user_display_name ($user_email)";
echo "<br />";
// do something...}
```

This is the random string thats currently displays on the front end
()
B (B)
W (W)
T (T)
t (t)
B (B)
b (b)
()
2 (2)
()
()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$users = get_field("pds_project_manager");
if( $users ): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $users as $user ): ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo esc_attr( $user->display_name ); ?><br/>
            <a href="mailto:<?php echo esc_attr($user->user_email); ?>"><?php echo $user->user_email; ?></a><br/>
            <?php the_field('company_name', 'user_'.$user->ID);?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, i have been messing with this and it just returns bullet points.

Comment: Also, I have an Acf field that shows a company name for each user, how do you think I should incorporate that? The field is company_name

Comment: @Webbb I've changed the code to add the `company_name` field. If the code returns only bullet points, you have to change the return format to object (ACF field settings). I guess at the moment it's an array.

Comment: Thank you, that worked and thank you for the quick response. I will mess with the company_name some more, but right now it doesn't show the company names from the users. using the_field('company_name', 'user_6') will work to show a single users company, but I am wanting to show the company name for each user that is selected in the pds_project_manager field.

Comment: You're right. Try this: `<?php the_field('company_name', 'user_'.$user->ID);?>`. See the code in my answer. If the answer works, it would be nice if you accept it :)